# Convert datatable to an array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datatable

I created a program where I use datatables to store some information and then upon a button click, it would display in a datagridview. Here is my code...can someone tell me how to create an array instead of this, I researched for hours and still no help.

```
 Dim Array As New DataTable
Dim array2 As New DataTable
Dim array3 As New DataTable

Public Class Degrees

    Public Property FieldofStudy As String
    Public Property Year1986 As String
    Public Property Year2006 As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal FieldofStudy As String, ByVal Year1986 As String, ByVal Year2006 As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Year1986 = Year1986
        Me.Year1986 = Year2006
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub btnChanges_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChanges.Click

    array2.Clear()
    Dim column4 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study")
    column4.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column5 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Change (1981-2006)")
    column5.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")


    array2.Columns.Add(column4)
    array2.Columns.Add(column5)

    ''Display array two containing percentage changes''
    array2.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "214.0%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "60.7%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Business", "58.6%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Engineering", "5.3%")
    array2.Rows.Add("Education", "-0.8%")

    dgvStudies.DataSource = array2

End Sub

Private Sub btnHistogram_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHistogram.Click

    array3.Clear()

    Dim column6 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study")
    column6.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column7 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("")
    column7.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column8 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Degrees in 2006")
    column8.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    array3.Clear()
    array3.Columns.Add(column6)
    array3.Columns.Add(column7)
    array3.Columns.Add(column8)

    array3.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "*****", "47,480")
    array3.Rows.Add("Engineering", "*******", "67,045")
    array3.Rows.Add("Education", "***********", "107,238")
    array3.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "****************", "161,485")
    array3.Rows.Add("Business", "********************************", "67,045")

    dgvStudies.DataSource = array3

End Sub

Private Sub btnQuit_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDegrees_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDegrees.Click

    Array.Clear()
    Dim column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study")
    column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("1981")
    column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Dim column3 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("2006")
    column3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    Array.Clear()
    Array.Columns.Add(column1)
    Array.Columns.Add(column2)
    Array.Columns.Add(column3)

    Array.Rows.Add("Business", "200,521", "318,042")
    Array.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "15,121", "47,480")
    Array.Rows.Add("Education", "108,074", "107,238")
    Array.Rows.Add("Engineering", "63,642", "67,045")
    Array.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "100,513", "161,485")

    Me.dgvStudies.DataSource = Array
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Why do wish to use arrays when Lists are dynamic and flexible? I would suggest creating a class to define your columns and a List(Of Columns) to bind to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

While your variables are named "array", "array2" and "array3", you have declared them as type `DataTable` which makes them `DataTable`s (not `Array`s). DataTables work fine as a DataSource for DataGridView.

Since you need them as an array, you can change your code to the following:

```
Public Class Changes
    Public Property FieldofStudy As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Change As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByRef FieldofStudy As String, ByRef Change As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Change = Change
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Histogram
    Public Property FieldofStudy As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Asterisks As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Degrees As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByRef FieldofStudy As String, ByRef Asterisks As String, ByRef Degrees As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Asterisks = Asterisks
        Me.Degrees = Degrees
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Degrees
    Public Property FieldofStudy As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Year1986 As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Year2006 As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByRef FieldofStudy As String, ByRef Year1986 As String, ByRef Year2006 As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Year1986 = Year1986
        Me.Year2006 = Year2006
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub btnChanges_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChanges.Click
    Dim dtChanges As DataTable = New DataTable("Changes")
    Dim dcDiscipline As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study", GetType(String))
    Dim dcChange As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Change (1981-2006)", GetType(String))
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim change As Changes = Nothing

    dtChanges.Columns.Add(dcDiscipline)
    dtChanges.Columns.Add(dcChange)

    'Display Degrees containing percentage changes
    dtChanges.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "214.0%")
    dtChanges.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "60.7%")
    dtChanges.Rows.Add("Business", "58.6%")
    dtChanges.Rows.Add("Engineering", "5.3%")
    dtChanges.Rows.Add("Education", "-0.8%")

    For Each row In dtChanges.Rows
        change = New Changes(row.Item(0), row.Item(1))
        list.Add(change)
    Next

    dgvStudies.DataSource = list
End Sub

Private Sub btnHistogram_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHistogram.Click
    Dim dtHistogram As DataTable = New DataTable("Histogram")
    Dim dcDiscipline As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study", GetType(String))
    Dim dcUnnamed As DataColumn = New DataColumn("", GetType(String))
    Dim dcDegrees2006 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Degrees in 2006", GetType(String))
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim histo As Histogram = Nothing

    dtHistogram.Columns.Add(dcDiscipline)
    dtHistogram.Columns.Add(dcUnnamed)
    dtHistogram.Columns.Add(dcDegrees2006)

    dtHistogram.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "*****", "47,480")
    dtHistogram.Rows.Add("Engineering", "*******", "67,045")
    dtHistogram.Rows.Add("Education", "***********", "107,238")
    dtHistogram.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "****************", "161,485")
    dtHistogram.Rows.Add("Business", "********************************", "67,045")

    For Each row In dtHistogram.Rows
        histo = New Histogram(row.Item(0), row.Item(1), row.Item(2))
        list.Add(histo)
    Next

    dgvStudies.DataSource = list
End Sub

Private Sub btnDegrees_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDegrees.Click
    Dim dtDegrees As DataTable = New DataTable("Degrees")
    Dim dcDiscipline As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Field of Study", GetType(String))
    Dim dcYear1986 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("1981", GetType(String))
    Dim dcYear2006 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("2006", GetType(String))
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim degree As Degrees = Nothing

    dtDegrees.Columns.Add(dcDiscipline)
    dtDegrees.Columns.Add(dcYear1986)
    dtDegrees.Columns.Add(dcYear2006)

    dtDegrees.Rows.Add("Business", "200,521", "318,042")
    dtDegrees.Rows.Add("Computer and info. science", "15,121", "47,480")
    dtDegrees.Rows.Add("Education", "108,074", "107,238")
    dtDegrees.Rows.Add("Engineering", "63,642", "67,045")
    dtDegrees.Rows.Add("Social sciences and history", "100,513", "161,485")

    For Each row In dtDegrees.Rows
        degree = New Degrees(row.Item(0), row.Item(1), row.Item(2))
        list.Add(degree)
    Next

    dgvStudies.DataSource = list
End Sub
```

**You can further simplify this by not using DataTables at all:**

```
Public Class Changes
    Public Property FieldofStudy As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Change As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByRef FieldofStudy As String, ByRef Change As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Change = Change
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Histogram
    Public Property FieldofStudy As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Asterisks As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Degrees As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByRef FieldofStudy As String, ByRef Asterisks As String, ByRef Degrees As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Asterisks = Asterisks
        Me.Degrees = Degrees
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Degrees
    Public Property FieldofStudy As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Year1986 As String = String.Empty
    Public Property Year2006 As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ByRef FieldofStudy As String, ByRef Year1986 As String, ByRef Year2006 As String)
        Me.FieldofStudy = FieldofStudy
        Me.Year1986 = Year1986
        Me.Year2006 = Year2006
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub btnChanges_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChanges.Click
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    'Display Degrees containing percentage changes
    list.Add(New Changes("Computer and info. science", "214.0%"))
    list.Add(New Changes("Social sciences and history", "60.7%"))
    list.Add(New Changes("Business", "58.6%"))
    list.Add(New Changes("Engineering", "5.3%"))
    list.Add(New Changes("Education", "-0.8%"))

    dgvStudies.DataSource = list
End Sub

Private Sub btnHistogram_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHistogram.Click
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    list.Add(New Histogram("Computer and info. science", "*****", "47,480"))
    list.Add(New Histogram("Engineering", "*******", "67,045"))
    list.Add(New Histogram("Education", "***********", "107,238"))
    list.Add(New Histogram("Social sciences and history", "****************", "161,485"))
    list.Add(New Histogram("Business", "********************************", "67,045"))

    dgvStudies.DataSource = list
End Sub

Private Sub btnDegrees_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDegrees.Click
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    list.Add(New Degrees("Business", "200,521", "318,042"))
    list.Add(New Degrees("Computer and info. science", "15,121", "47,480"))
    list.Add(New Degrees("Education", "108,074", "107,238"))
    list.Add(New Degrees("Engineering", "63,642", "67,045"))
    list.Add(New Degrees("Social sciences and history", "100,513", "161,485"))

    dgvStudies.DataSource = list
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this but can you show me how to put the data into an array. I know it was easier for the datatable and what you did but I have to have it in an array.

Comment: Please clarify. Does it need to be a typed array? How many dimensions? What is the ultimate purpose of the Array? Where will it be used?

Comment: It is a multi-dimensional array. And it needs to have 3 dimensions for the degrees and 2 for the histogram and percentage changed. The array is just to store the information then output it to the datagridview. Sorry I'm not really sure anything aside from that. It just needs to display the same output as the data table that I wrote.